# Check whenever an external command is called from an user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to know if this was possible to know whenever an user uses a command from another bot, or from Discord integrated commands such as "/tableflip"

It does not seem to show up from `on_message` nor `on_message_delete`

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get commands like `-help` you should enable all the intents by going on the dev portal (if you can't find them i suggest you google them) and by doing this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix, intents=intents)


client.run("token")
```

But if you are trying to get commands like /help, you can only get the bots response, not the executed command itself as it will return blank. (I didn't test this, so you could try doing the steps above and see if this works)